# How to allow only letters in C# form tex tbox?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, forms, textbox

I want to create c# form textbox in my application. (does not allow numbers spaces and symbols )

```
 private void txtinput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtinput.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
                txtinput.Text.Remove(txtinput.Text.Length - 1);
            }
        }
```

Even I use above code does not appear message box when I type numbers in the text box ?

What is the wrong with my code. Please help

Comment: A negative character class is written like this `[^a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex, you can just check if any of the texts characters aren't letters using linq

```
txtinput.Text.Any(c => !Char.IsLetter(c));
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/cmLhpD)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one out: `^[a-zA-Z]*$`